# Simple Perl Regex parser

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Hey, I am working on a very basic parser. I am almost certain that my regex is correct, but values do not seem to be being stored in my `$1` and `$2`. Am I doing something wrong? I am just looking for tips to alter my code. Thanks for any advice! Also, I am new to Perl, so if I did something wrong, I am looking to get off on the right foot and develop solid habits.

Sample line from file:

```
Sat 02-August-2008 20:47 - 123.112.3.209 - "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;
```

I am just getting the hours from the times.

```
foreach my $line (@lines)
{   
my $match =~ /\d\d-\w+-\d{4} (\d)(\d):\d\d/;

if( $1 == 0)
{
    $times[$2] = $times[$2] + 1;
}
else
{   
    my $time = $1.$2;
    $times[$time] = $times[$time]+ 1;
}
 }


print "\n";
for(my $i=0;$i<24;$i++)
{
print "$i: $times[$i]\n";
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to parse? We're not psychics here, you know.

Comment: @jesperE editing with sample.

Comment: I know that I am getting the lines from the file. I tested that earlier and was able to reprint each line inside my loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to match on `$line` shouldn't the code read

```
$line =~ /\d\d-\w+-\d{4} (\d)(\d):\d\d/;
```

[See here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#op_=%7E).

Comment: Hm, I made that change and is still not working. My $1 and $2 seem to be empty. I appreciate the tip and I think you might be right about it having to be $line, but since I am a beginner at best to Perl, I am not certain

Comment: I'm getting 2 and 0, from the sample line just as expected. You did get rid of `my` in front of `$line` right?

Comment: haha, thanks for seeing through my newness. I appreciate you taking the time to help. Have a great night.

Answer (score 3):

Can you give some example of what kind of pattern you are try to match? Otherwise I won't be able to tell if your regex matches your pattern or not. However there are some improvements you can make about your code:

First off, always test if a match is successful if you want to use $1, $2 etc

```
if($match =~ /\d\d-\w+-\d{4} (\d)(\d):\d\d/) {

    if( $1 == 0)
    {
        $times[$2] = $times[$2] + 1;
    }
    else
    {   
        my $time = $1.$2;
        $times[$time] = $times[$time]+ 1;
    }
} else {
    warn "no match!\n";
}
```

Second, always use the '-w' switch. In this case, you will probably get the warning message about $1 and $2 are not initialized due to failed match:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I really appreciate it. The other fellow's answer solved my issue, so there is no need to look into my issue in more detail. But, I will incorporate your tips into my code. Have a great evening

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are new to Perl, one of the strengths is CPAN and the many solutions there. Don't reinvent the wheel!

There is a great module called [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/lib/Date/Parse.pm) that will parse the time part for you. Then the only regex problem that you have is separating out the time part of your line.

Based on your one line sample, this code will do that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Parse;

my $line="Sat 02-August-2008 20:47 - 123.112.3.209 - \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;";
my $tmpart;

if ($line=~ /^(.*\d+:\d+) -/) {
    $tmpart=$1;

    print "Time part = $tmpart\n";

    my $time=str2time($tmpart);
    my ($ss,$mm,$hh,$day,$month,$year,$zone) = strptime($tmpart);

    $year+=1900;
    $month+=1;

    print "Unix time: $time\n";
    print "Parsed time: $month/$day/$year $hh:$mm:$ss  \n\n";
} 
else {
   warn "no match!\n";
}
```

This will return a Unix time number that is then easy to work with. Or (as shown) you can parse the individual components of the time.

Comment: This line creates some problems:  `my $tmpart = $1 if $line=~ /^(.*\d+:\d+) -/;`  If your regex fails to match, `$tmpart` is undefined, and you will get a bunch of warnings and bogus results.

Comment: Easy fix with some error logic code. Done! Thanks for pointing it out.